# OrientDB traversal changes sorting

Tags: graph-theory, gremlin, orientdb, graph-traversal

I have a simple OrientDB graph that looks like this :

[image]

I'm observing a strange behaviour regarding sorting. The following query retrieves all the `Child` vertices of a specified `Parent` which are linked to this `Parent` by an `Edge` with a specific `property` value. It also sorts the results by the Child `name` property :

```
select *
from (traverse outE("Edge").inV("Child") from {ParentId} MAXDEPTH 5)
where property = 'something'
order by name desc
```

Despite the `order by name` the results are not accurately sorted. The string case seems to be taken into consideration. However, the `Child` `name` property is defined as a Case Insensitive String and the `Child` vertex has a `NOT_UNIQUE` index on `name` so this should be an issue.

So with the following setup:

```
CREATE VERTEX VParent extends V;
CREATE VERTEX VChild extends V;
CREATE EDGE EEdge extends E;

CREATE PROPERTY VChild.property STRING (COLLATE "ci");
CREATE INDEX VChild.property ON VChild (property) NOTUNIQUE;

let $parent = CREATE VERTEX VParent;

let $childA = CREATE VERTEX VChild SET property = "© 2019";
let $childB = CREATE VERTEX VChild SET property = "test";
let $childC = CREATE VERTEX VChild SET property = "2018";
let $childD = CREATE VERTEX VChild SET property = "© 2016";
let $childE = CREATE VERTEX VChild SET property = "Face";
let $childF = CREATE VERTEX VChild SET property = "Test2";

CREATE EDGE EEdge FROM $parent to $childA;
CREATE EDGE EEdge FROM $parent to $childB;
CREATE EDGE EEdge FROM $parent to $childC;
CREATE EDGE EEdge FROM $parent to $childD;
CREATE EDGE EEdge FROM $parent to $childE;
CREATE EDGE EEdge FROM $parent to $childF;
```

Then the following query:

```
select *
from (traverse outE("EEdge").inV("VChild") from $parent.id MAXDEPTH 5)
order by property desc;
```

should yield a case insensitve sort thus:

```
$childA (property = "@ 2019")
$childD (property = "@ 2016")
$childB (property = "test")
$childF (property = "Test2")
$childE (property = "Face")
$childC (property = "2018")
```

but instead yields:

```
$childB (property = "test")
$childA (property = "@ 2019")
$childD (property = "@ 2016")
$childF (property = "Test2")
$childE (property = "Face")
$childC (property = "2018")
```

However, if I remove the `traverse` subquery and replace it with a simple `from VChild` the sorting works fine:

```
select *
from VChild
order by property desc;
```

Any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: This question seems to be related to OrientDB SQL rather than Gremlin. Also what would be the expected output: how do you expect elements to be sorted? You might need to add the current output vs the expected output.

Comment: @jbmusso updated the original question. The issue is clearly the traversal but I have no idea why...